# Covering of a surface of a cube $n\times n \times n$ by pieces of paper $1\times 6$

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling, puzzle, combinatorial-group-theory

When I was too young one of my problems was in the list of problems of All-Russian Olympiad. The problem is the following:

**Problem.** We have a surface of a cube $n\times n \times n$ such that each face is divided in $n^2$ unit squares. Then this surface was covered (once) by $3n^2$ pieces of paper $1\times 2$ (domino) without overlapping.
Prove that if $n$ is odd than the number of bent "dominos" is also odd.

**Comment.** This problem is not very difficult therefore it was solved by 90% participants in 10th grade (about 63 of 70). The solution you can find here.
[You really need it?)](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h147166p832743)

---

"Hm..." - I thought - "What will be with $1\times 6$?".
It was obvious for myself that it is impossible to cover the surface for $n=1$, but possible for $n=2, 3, 4$... $n=6$...

Aga, if $n$ is even than we can divide faces in two groups (in each group $3$ faces) in such way that faces in one group forms on surface of the cube rectangle $3n\times n$ with $2$ "bends". Each rectangle can be easily divided in pieces of paper $1\times 6$.

The case when $3$ is a divisor of $n$ I am leaving for a reader.

After that I conjectured the following.

> **Conjecture.** For $n$ such that $(n, 6)=1$ there is no such covering of the surface of the cube $n\times n \times n$ by $n^2$ pieces of paper $1\times 6$ without overlapping.

Then I prove that it is true for $n=5$ and some my friends found a more or less suitable proof but it does not work in general case (they understood that vertices of this cube are weak points in this problem).

---

Finally, this conjecture was disproved (for $n=11$) by Peter Mueller(see his answer below)!

Also I like to add one problem (Russian olympiad folklore):

**Problem.** Let $n$ be such natural number that $(n,3)=1$, then there is no covering of three faces of a cube $n\times n \times n$ with a common vertex (of this cube) by strips $1\times 3$.

Comment: This doesn't feel like the right place for this question. Maybe artofproblemsolving.com?

Comment: @Tony: Why isn't this a right place? Because the author didn't ask about $1\times3$ covers first? ;-)

Comment: @WadimZudilin: I think this is a very nice puzzle, but not a mathematics research question.

Comment: I think just the opposite! Serious research is fun!

Comment: Later I will add some information to my text and maybe it will become much more serious. Today I cann't even use my computer. Shabbat! Tsss.... please, don't tell in my synagogue that I added a comment here.

Comment: If questions of tiling two-dimensional shapes by polyforms were mathematical enough to be studied by Conway and Thurston (http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2324578) they should be mathematical enough even for the most snobbish on this board.

Comment: David, Sure, I want to add something in this direction (I mean Convey's group)

Comment: How far has the "Russian olympiad folklore" conjecture been tested?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: It is a solved olympiad problem. I put it here just to give other mathematicians an opportunity to solve that elegant problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Indeed, there is no solution for $n=5$, and also none for $n=7$. However, for $n=11$ there is a tiling of the requested form. I found it using a straightforward exact cover formulation and [Knuth's original exact cover solver](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/programs/dance.w). I'm not sure how to best visualize a solution, here is an attempt using random colors for the tiles. It is a little hard to check that all tiles continue correctly across the cut edges of the cube:
[image]

**Added later:** Fedja suggested in his comment to more generally look at $1\times 6$ tilings of a $m\times n\times k$ cuboid, for it is easy to see that such a tiling yields a tiling of a $(m+6)\times n\times k$ cuboid.

Indeed, the covering of the $11\times11\times11$ cuboid can be obtained from the way faster to compute covering of the $5\times11\times11$ cuboid:
[image]

As to the $13\times13\times13$ case, the programs (Knuth's cover and alternatively integer linear program solvers) are still running. There are no solutions for $13\times7\times7$ and $13\times13\times1$. I don't know yet about $13\times13\times7$ and $13\times13\times13$.

Comment: How do you prove that there are no tilings for $n=7$?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: Just by brute force checking whether there is an exact cover. For $n=7$ Knuth's program took 8 seconds, while it took several hours for $n=11$ until it started to through out some solutions.

Comment: Oh, I am impressed that this is not computationally hopeless. 349 squares, 49 tiles, so many variants to put them! What is general complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: @PeterMueller: Wow!!!

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I know nothing about the complexity of Knuth's algorithm X which is a straightforward idea to solve exact cover problems by backtracking. However, the exact cover problem is NP complete, so this algorithm certainly works only for not too big problems.

Comment: @PeterMueller is it NP-complete for $1\times 6$? For $1\times 2$ probably no, as it is a partial case of the perfect matching problem.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Sorry, my remark was for the general exact cover problem. I do not know about the cases where the sets have a fixed small size.

Comment: Re the time complexity of Algorithm X: see http://11011110.livejournal.com/128249.html — there are faster algorithms known (in theory) for exact satisfiability, but they are all still exponential, and X is fast in practice.

Comment: Actually, it is easy to show that if $m\times n\times k$ is coverable, then so is $(m+6)\times n\times k$ (just think of all strips crossing the edges of the face to move and elongate them by 6 units inserting formal $0\times 1$ strips along the edge where nothing is really bent; then split each $12\times 1$ into two $6\times 1$). Thus, to finish off the cube problem for good, it would be nice to do the $n=13$ case as well. I don't think it should be much harder for the computer than $n=11$ and I'll be quite surprised if nothing shows up. :)

Comment: Also, since we can cover $11\times 11\times 11$ by $6\times 1$, we can cover $55\times 55\times 55$ by $30\times 5$ and, thereby, by $6\times 1$, which takes care of $n=6m+1$ for $m\ge 9$. Thus, the number of exceptional cubes is finite.

Comment: "I don't know yet about 13×13×7 and 13×13×13" Any update after 2 months of "running the programs"? :-)

Comment: @fedja: Oh, I had stopped the programs after a few days :-(